# Retornar valor default em consulta mysql

Tags: mysql

Possuo uma **query** que, em determinadas situações não retorna valor.

Neste caso gostaria de obter o valor 0, tentei usar o `ifnull`, mas sem sucesso.

```
SELECT ifnull((valor * t1.PBRT),'0') AS C_MP
            FROM engenharia_custo_mp t0
                ,(
                    SELECT MEDIDA1
                        ,PBRT
                    FROM engenharia_produto
                    WHERE codigo = '0304502500701'
                    ) t1
                ,(
                    SELECT MAT_PRIMAPK
                    FROM engenharia_materia_prima
                    WHERE DESCRICAO = (
                            SELECT MAT_PRIMAFK
                            FROM engenharia_produto
                            WHERE codigo = '0304502500701'
                            )
                    ) t2
            WHERE t1.MEDIDA1 = t0.ESPESSURA
                AND t2.MAT_PRIMAPK = t0.MAT_PRIMAFK2
```

Comment: Atualizar a tabela de origem é uma opção ?

Comment: não, este caso de não retornar valor pode ser comum, não impacta no processo, porém gostaria d identificar, através do select, casos de retorno nulo.

Answer (score 3):

Se os campos da sua tabela for do tipo INT, o resultado desta operação vai ser 0, pois não existe NULL nos campos INTEIROS

```
SELECT COALESCE(valor * t1.PBRT, 0) AS C_MP 
   FROM....
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar o `case`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.PBRT > 0 THEN valor * t1.PBRT ELSE 0 END CASE AS C_MP
```

[Documentação do CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)